# Enviar correo desde java

Tags: java, email, java-8, gmail

quiero enviar un correo desde mi programa en Java 8 a un destinatario configurable (gmail, hotmail o corporativo) sin tener que autentificar al remitente o hacer un login, para enviar el correo. ¿Es esto posible en Java 8?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Get system properties
            Properties props = System.getProperties();

            // Setup mail server
            //props.put("mail.smtp.host", "192.168.1.111");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", "ejemplo@gmail.com");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

            // Get session
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            // Define message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("ejemplo@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("asunto");
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress("cmedina@imptec.com.pe"));
            message.setText("gracias Chuidiang");
            // Envia el mensaje
            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Fallo sendEmail al enviar Correo: " +e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
>         nested exception is:
>           java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2194)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:726)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
>           at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
>           at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
>           at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
>           at pe.com.imptec.itickets.test.SendCorreoTest2.main(SendCorreoTest2.java:33)
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>           at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:352)
>           at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
>           at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160)
>           ... 7 more

Comment: Podrias modificar la pregunta y agregar el codigo que ya tienes hecho

Comment: @RaulCacacho ya está

Comment: yo veo que la tienes comentada esta linea  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);     y te falta estas otras properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Comment: @RaulCacacho pero si no quisiera usar un host smtp? y solo enviar un correo al destinatario

Comment: Seria así  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");

Comment: Pero eso lo haces aqui message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("ejemplo@gmail.com")); ahi lo envias a un destinatario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tu código le falta la configuración para conectarse adecuadamente al host con las credenciales correctas):

```
final String username = "ejemplo@gmail.com";
final String password = "password";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
      }
  });

try {

      // Define message
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
      message.setSubject("asunto");
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress("cmedina@imptec.com.pe"));
      message.setText("gracias Chuidiang");
      // Envia el mensaje
      Transport.send(message);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

**Ojo** que aún así el código puede fallar, si es así asegurate que permites a aplicaciones menos seguras acceder a tu cuenta yendo [acá](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1)

Comment: No funciona, no se si será que es una api antigua o que.